# Cant import data into mongo database using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, macos, robo3t, mongodb-atlas

I can't import data into my existing database located on mongoDBAtlas. I installed and connected robomongo with mongoDBAtlas for working with atlas.

I created new database **jasper** and collection **User** in robomongo then
I created user.json file in my project where are stored my data.

I followed tutorial on https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongoimport/ - how to use mongoimport with mongodb.

Here is my command, Im typing in terminal:

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb://Morty:<PASSWORD>@jasper-shard-00-00-mrihb.mongodb.net:27017/jasper?ssl=true&replicaSet=jasper-shard-0&authSource=admin --collection User --drop --file ./src/data/user.json --jsonArray
```

that give me an error:

```
[1] 40930
[2] 40931
-bash: --collection: command not found
[2]+  Done                    replicaSet=jasper-shard-0
KSC1-LMC-K00587:Interview-test-part-one marze$ 2017-10-15T10:38:35.209+0200 no collection specified
2017-10-15T10:38:35.209+0200    using filename '' as collection
2017-10-15T10:38:35.209+0200    error validating settings: invalid collection name: collection name cannot be an empty string
2017-10-15T10:38:35.209+0200    try 'mongoimport --help' for more information
```

If I run mongoimport  for **localhost** it works perfectly.

Where should be the problem ?

Comment: Put quotes around the uri connection string. You have an `&` in there which your shell ( bash,zsh, whatever ) thinks you mean something different by.

Comment: @NeilLunn really thanks for advice.  That was the problem :)

Comment: FYI. Any document that is telling you to specify `authSource=admin` is really out of date. The general drivers ( and therefore the tools ) just do this by default, so it's not really needed. It's also a compatibilty issue for upcoming MongoDB 3.6 if there are users defined anywhere else other than `admin`.

Comment: @Morten could you post an answer to the question yourself instead of editing it in to help future readers?

Comment: May be useful this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078520/mongodb-how-to-import-dump-data-from-gz-file/53079408#53079408

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
-use quotes for uri param.

```
mongoimport --uri "mongodb://Morty:<PASSWORD>@jasper-shard-00-00-mrihb.mongodb.net:27017/jasper?ssl=true&replicaSet=jasper-shard-0&authSource=admin" --collection User --drop --file ./src/data/user.json --jsonArray
```