# MongoDb: How to import dump data from .gz file?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongodump, mongorestore

I want to import dump data from my `.gz` file.

Location of file is `home/Alex/Documents/Abc/dump.gz` and the name of db is `"Alex"`.

I have tried `mongorestore --gzip --db "Alex" /home/Alex/Documents/Abc/dump.gz`

But it shows error:

```
 2018-10-31T12:54:58.359+0530   the --db and --collection args should 
 only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are 
 deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
 2018-10-31T12:54:58.359+0530   Failed: file 
 /home/Alex/Documents/Abc/dump.gz does not have .bson extension.
```

How can I import it?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Dump command:

```
mongodump --host localhost:27017 --gzip --db Alex --out ./testSO
```

Restore Command:

```
mongorestore --host localhost:27017 --gzip --db Alex ./testSO/Alex
```

Works perfectly!

---

#### While using archive:

Dump command:

```
mongodump --host localhost:27017 --archive=dump.gz --gzip --db Alex
```

Restore Command:

```
mongorestore --host localhost:27017 --gzip --archive=dump.gz --db Alex
```

---

> **Note:-** While using archive you need to stick with the `database name`.

Different database name or collection name is not supported. For [more info](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-7573).

Comment: "the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future;"

Comment: I have `json` and `bson` files from dump. `--gzip` without `--db` failed for me.

Comment: `mongorestore --host localhost:27017 --gzip --archive=dump.gz --db Alex`
this command does not work for me. I am getting an error same as @SantiagoBendavid.

Comment: Just in case you're asking (like myself) `27017` is the default MongoDB port: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/index.html

Comment: mongorestore --gzip --archive=/path/to/file.gz --db  works for me

Comment: different db names are supported with nsTo and nsFrom parameter fields of mongorestore utility

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me in the latest versions (`100.5.1`) of mongodump.

```sh
mongorestore --uri=<CONNECTION_URI> --gzip --archive=<ARCHIVE_NAME> --nsFrom "<SOURCE_DB_NAME>.*" --nsTo "<DEST_DB_NAME>.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpack .tgz files and restore the DB

tar zxvf fileNameHere.tgz

mongorestore --port 27017 -u="username" -p="password" --authenticationDatabase admin /bacup_path

Answer (score 0):

**mongorestore** doesn't find the *BSON* files inside the gzip file because the *mongodump* was made with different paths than the restore one.

To solve the problem, the fastest and safest way is to extract the gzip file  and go to the upper folder containing the *json* and *bson* files for run the mongorestore.

For example, the `dump.gz` file was made in such a way that the backup are saved within the `data/backup/mongo/dump/` path folders

Extracting the `dump.gz` file with command `tar -xvf dump.gz` you will find a folder named data with the subfolders `data/backup/mongo/dump/` inside (**inside** the `dump` folder are present **all backup file with json and bson extension**, these files represent databases and collections, etc.)

Go to the **higher** folder, that containing the `dump` folder eg. `cd data/backup/mongo/`

Now you can run the restore command

```
mongorestore --authenticationDatabase admin dump/
```

Where `dump/` is the folder that containing the backup files.

You may need to use the arguments `-h` to point the *server host* (eg. *localhost*) and `-u` followed by the *username* enabled to make the restore operations (eg. *root*)